# Unicode Japanese prolonged sound mark excluded from Kana script?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, cjk

I'm trying to cleanup a string by removing special characters to make a slug. That said, I want to keep CJK characters otherwise there's nothing left for these languages.

So I have a regex that is supposed to keep CJK characters by listing the scripts:

```
"[^-_.\\w-\\p{script=Han}\\p{script=Hira}\\p{script=Kana}\\p{script=Hang}]"
```

The problem is, the katakana prolonged sound mark "ー" seems to be excluded.

http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x30FC/index.html

Here is the code showing the problem:

https://github.com/erwan/unicode-java-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/Hello.java

Is it not in the scripts I listed?

edit: ok, code here if you prefer, but it doesn't give much more information than the regex itself. It's mostly useful so people can try it.

```
package com.example;

class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "%;アレルギー[]abcd";
        String output= input.replaceAll("[^-_.\\w-\\p{script=Han}\\p{script=Hira}\\p{script=Kana}\\p{script=Hang}]", "");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is in \p{Lm} category, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30fc/index.htm. Does adding the character to the negated character class solve the issue? What is the exact problem?

Comment: stribizhev yes, that fixes it. Thank you!

Comment: Note that there are many non-Japanese characters that match the `\p{Lm}` category.

Comment: @erwan. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as a matter of fact, it is not in the scripts listed. The [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt) places this character in the `Common` script.

One should differentiate between "script" and "block" in Unicode. That character belongs to the Katakana *block*, along with a few other characters which are not letters such as the "Katakana iteration mark" (`\u30fd`). But it does not belong to the Katakana *script*. Only the actual syllables belong in the Katakana script.

One thing you can do is replace the `script` indication to `block` for `Katakana`:

```
output = input.replaceAll("[^-_.\\w-\\p{script=Han}\\p{script=Hira}\\p{block=Katakana}\\p{script=Hang}]", "");
```

The output in this case would include the prolonged sound mark.

Or you can do it like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^-_.\\w]",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(input);
output = m.replaceAll("");
```

This pattern will match all word characters, in all languages, including, but not limited to Japanese.

For the input string `"%;アレルギー[]{}=abceⸯd漢字ру́сский"`, this will yield

```
アレルギーabceⸯd漢字ру́сский
```

Whereas my first suggestion, the one with the block, the output will be:

```
アレルギーabced漢字
```

So if you just want to limit to Japanese (and Korean), my first suggestion might suit your better, whereas if you want all international word characters, the second will be better.

Comment: Or `\\p{InKatakana}` - thanks for the remark on my former answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually the best answer possible. I did this with Japanese because I know Japanese but we have users in many other non-latin languages who will be happy to have there words kept.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid matching that character, you should add it to the negated class.

```
"[^-_ー.\\w-\\p{script=Han}\\p{script=Hira}\\p{script=Kana}\\p{script=Hang}]"
```